# Lg-H500f Magna USB Debugging Android Studio

Tags: android, macos, adb, lg

I'am using Android Studio 1.2 and OS X Yosemite to develop Android applications, I have turned on USB Debugging and the phone has the Media Device (MTP) option selected. When I run `adb devices` no devices attached are listed. I have seen some answers suggesting to download a driver but I can't even find the devices in the LG web site.

Has anyone solved already the problem?

Comment: check if you can see it with https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/usb-device-info/igkmggljimacfdfalpeelenjeicmfnll

Comment: I can't see it with that applications. I can transfer my files with Android File Transfer though

Comment: I finally solved it. All I had to do was changing the type of USB connection from the device from Media Device (MTP) to Send images (PTP)

Answer (score 1):

if you did not see in the comments, I finally solved it. All I had to do was change the type of USB connection from the device from Media Device (MTP) to Send images (PTP)